# Subsetting array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

Well, I want to change the zero elements, for example, (that they are zeros is not the point) and I am using this code, but when I'll go to subset it doesn´t do it well.

```
matrix = [ -1 1 0; 2 0 -2; 0 3 -3]
[rows,cols] = find(matrix==0)


matrix =
    -1     1     0
     2     0    -2
     0     3    -3
rows =
     3
     2
     1
cols =
     1
     2
     3


matrix(rows,cols)
ans =
     0     3    -3
     2     0    -2
    -1     1     0
```

why is this returning the entire matrix when is it only three single elements?

So if I do matrix(rows,cols)=1 it returns the entire matrix as 1 and not only the zero elements.

Comment: The documentation [explains what is happening](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). Use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

Comment: The reason this is not working the way you expect it to is that you are not asking for 3 elements, you are asking for 3 rows and, within those 3 rows, 3 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB syntax provides several options to access non-consecutive elements in an array.

One way to solve your problem would be to use [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511).

Let

```
matrix = [ -1 1 0; 2 0 -2; 0 3 -3]
```

and

```
[rows,cols] = find(matrix == 0).
```

Then

```
sub2ind(size(matrix),rows,cols)
```

returns the linear indices of the selected elements, i.e. the vector `[3;5;7]`.

Now

```
matrix(sub2ind(size(matrix),rows,cols)) = 1
```

would produce

```
matrix =

  -1   1   1
   2   1  -2
   1   3  -3
```

Exactly as you would expect.

### Explanation

With linear indexing the elements of an `MxN` MATLAB matrix get consecutive numbers in a flat 1-dimensional array of length `M * N`.

In fact returning linear indices is the default mode of operation for MATLAB function

```
    k = find(X).
```

As @beaker pointed out in the comments you can just use the output of `find(X)` as in

```
   matrix(find(matrix == 0)) = 1.
```

However if you have already got the vectors of row and column indices also known as subscripts, you could convert them into linear indices using the `sub2ind` function.

Comment: Why not just `indices = find(matrix == 0)`?